# How can I add/edit geotag data for one particular photo?

Tags: metadata, geotagging

How can I geotag one particular photo? Or edit a photo with incorrect geo data?

I'm using GPSLogger in my android phone to record GPS data and later sync them to my photos using GPicSync. But I sometimes find a few photos with wrong geo tags.

Can I geotag one particular photo manually or edit one with the wrong data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GPicSync features list implies that it can do this, but I didn't see any documentation as to how, so if it's not discoverable from the interface, you can [use exiftool directly](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/GPS.html) like this:

```
exiftool -gpslatitude="$lat" -gpslatituderef="$lat" -gpslongitude="$lon" -gpslongituderef="$lon" "$filename"
```

where "$lat" and "$lon" are the lattitude and longitude in decimal degrees, degrees-minutes, or degrees-minutes-seconds as floating point numbers.

Comment: This answer was super useful to me; I wrapped the exiftool command in a little bash script so I wouldn't forget it: https://gist.github.com/fusionfox/fcaf97eafcfc7ebef3edd3f8eb8f0c5c ./geotag.sh 53.817046 -3.016336 ./zoo_photos/* (Note that I added the `-overwrite_original` flag, so it will modify any files you run it against)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/en). It is a freeware tool for Windows. GeoSetter uses Exiftool for writing tags, but provides an easy to use GUI.

It lets you select what photos you want to geotag, or you can edit existing tags. You can tag photos by synchronising with a GPS file, or pick the location on a map, or enter the latitude/longitude manually.

If you don't have a valid GPS track, the easiest option is to pick the location on the map (Google Maps or OpenStreetMap). Click on the map to add a marker, then click on that marker and choose "Assign Position to Selected Images". Or if the image is already geotagged, you can drag the marker to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the photos on you android you can use the android app https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/ that i implemented. it has multi-selection support and you can use a map to select the geo-location you want to assign.

unfortunately the app only works with photos that are stored on the android device.

the free app is not available on google play store but you can get it via [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/) or download it via https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=de.k3b.android.androFotoFinder

Howto geotag the photos

- Start the app in gallery view
- use the "filter" menu/icon to find photos you want to tag:

  - filter by folder and/or date range
- ==> the gallery is populated with all photos that match thi filter
- via multiselection mark all photos that should receive the same geo location.

  - long tap on the first image ==> it is marked with "[V]"
  - short tap on additional images from the same location
- use the "set geo" menu to start tagging

  - select "pick from map" if you want to pick the geo-location from a map
  - select "pick from photo" if you want to pick the geo-location from a photo that has geo-location

Comment: Please states that this app is yours.

Comment: @Olivier: done: added ownership

Answer (score 0):

You can add GPS tag on photos along with date and timestamp in the easiest way using one Android application named, "GPS Map Stamp: Geotag Photos with Timestamp Camera"!

Using this app you can add accurate geolocation with ease on Gallery photos & also on pics, that captured using this GPS Map camera. At a time, you can add stamps on 10 Gallery pictures!

You can check it out here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photolocationstamp.gpsmapgeotagongalleryphotos

Comment: Please list your affiliation with the linked product. Thanks!

Comment: I am a developer of this app!

Answer (score -1):

If you use a Mac, there's a $4 geotagging app called Photo GeoTag from the Mac App Store:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-geotag/id957217448?mt=12

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with this app. If so, please disclose. Also please add why it is better than other apps.

Comment: Yes, I am the developer of this app. Where do I disclose this?  In my comments?  Profile?  My reasons why this app is better may not be objective, but I believe it's easier and usually cheaper than the competition.  I'm always finding ways to improve it based on user feedback.  In fact there's a new version coming out in a few days that removes the recompressing the image after geotagging the app.  I hope that helps.